Use R dplyr to calculate N averages between two dates in a time series
I am trying to calculate averages of a value in a time series between many start and end dates.
A simple set up:
time_series <- tibble(dates=seq.Date(from=ymd('20240101'), to=ymd('20241231'), 'day'),
                      value = runif(366,max=10))
                      

target_dates <-tibble(id=c('A','B','C'),
                      start=ymd(c('20240104','20240504','20240704')),
                      end  =ymd(c('20240201','20240524','20240924'))) %>% 
               mutate(ndays=as.integer(end-start))

I'd like to calculate the mean of time_series$value between each target_dates$start and target_dates$end.
I'm unable to figure how to do this from two separate tibbles.
My first thought was this (and variations on this attempt).
target_dates %>% 
  group_by(start) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(time_series %>% slice(first(which(dates==start)):slice(last(which(dates==end)))) %>% select(values)))

But, that didn't work.
This also came to mind but does not work b/c because the between function does not work on vectors.   I could write a for loop, but that's not elegant.
time_series %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(value[between(target_dates$start,target_dates$end)]))

The column ndays is calculated because I tried using slide_idx_double from the slider library but could not figure out how to add the time series data to a statement that started with
time_series %>%
    summarise(avg = slide_index_dbl(WHAT GOES HERE??,start,.after=ndays,mean))

What I'm expecting is a tibble/data frame to be created in which the average of the time series time_series tibble value column is calculated between the target_dates start and end dates.
Help is appreciated.

See if joining works with your data
library(dplyr)

right_join(time_series, target_dates, join_by(between(dates, start, end))) %>% 
  summarize(Mean = mean(value), .by = c(id, start, end))
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  id    start      end         Mean
  <chr> <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1 A     2024-01-04 2024-02-01  5.23
2 B     2024-05-04 2024-05-24  5.09
3 C     2024-07-04 2024-09-24  4.96

Note, using set.seed to get a consistent data set
Data
set.seed(1)

time_series <- tibble(dates=seq.Date(from=ymd('20240101'), 
                 to=ymd('20241231'), 'day'),
                      value = runif(366,max=10))
                      

target_dates <-tibble(id=c('A','B','C'),
                      start=ymd(c('20240104','20240504','20240704')),
                      end  =ymd(c('20240201','20240524','20240924'))) %>% 
               mutate(ndays=as.integer(end-start))


An elegant answer.   Thank you.

Please try the below
cross_join(time_series, target_dates) %>% filter(between(dates, start, end)) %>% 
  group_by(id, start, end) %>% 
  summarise(mean=mean(value))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Groups:   id, start [3]
  id    start      end          mean
  <chr> <date>     <date>     <dbl>
1 A     2024-01-04 2024-02-01  5.41
2 B     2024-05-04 2024-05-24  5.37
3 C     2024-07-04 2024-09-24  4.85



This also works.  I chose the first answer b/c it was first and also because I believe it will scale better with a very large number of rows of data in the time series.

Here's a purrr/lubridate alternative without join:
# Toy data generated with `set.seed(1)`
library(tidyverse)

my_output <- mutate(
  target_dates,
  mean_value = map2_dbl(
    start, end, 
    \(x, y) mean(time_series$value[time_series$dates %within% (x %--% y)])))

The output:
> my_output
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  id    start      end        ndays mean_value
  <chr> <date>     <date>     <int>      <dbl>
1 A     2024-01-04 2024-02-01    28       5.23
2 B     2024-05-04 2024-05-24    20       5.09
3 C     2024-07-04 2024-09-24    82       4.96

